# "string.match()" is not a function?

Tags: javascript, regex, function, object, for-loop

I wrote a function to count the length and vowels in a word and output them in objects in an array. Yet I get the error "word.match() is not a function" where word is a string.

```
function wordData(string){
  var stringSplit = string.split(' ');
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0; i <= stringSplit.length; i++){
    var eachWord = stringSplit[i];
    var vowel = eachWord.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
    var vowelCount = vowel ? vowel.length : 0;
    var objectData = {};
    objectData.word = eachWord;
    objectData.length = eachWord.length;
    objectData.vowels = vowelCount;
    output.push(objectData);
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(wordData('some really awesome string'));
```

any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for(var i = 0; i <= stringSplit.length; i++)`

That'll go up past the last index of your array of strings. Therefore, it will be `undefined`, and you can't call `match` on `undefined`.

Do this instead:

`for(var i = 0; i < stringSplit.length; i++)`

Comment: Or of course, `stringSplit.forEach(function(eachWord) { /*...*/ })`

Answer (score 4):

Index out of bounds

```
for(var i = 0; i <= stringSplit.length; i++){
```

should be

```
for(var i = 0; i < stringSplit.length; i++){
```